# Swipeable views in for each individual navigation drawer item

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

My app has a navigation drawer with a few items and have 2 swipeable views. My question is, how can I make those swipeable views have different title and content depending on what navigation drawer item I click on. Currently I click on any navigation drawer item it displays the same swipeable views.

Please let me know if you need some clarification or something. Thanks!

Edit: Just so I'm clear. I don't mean swipeable views inside the nav drawer. When I tap on the nav drawer item, it takes me to that layout.

EDIT:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

    //Pager
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence Titles[] = {"Home", "Events"};
    int Numboftabs = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

        // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
        displayView(0);

        // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);

        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        /*
        if(id == R.id.action_search){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        */

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new ArithmeticFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.nav_item_arithmetic);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new AreaFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.nav_item_area);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new ProbabilityFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.nav_item_probability);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            // set the toolbar title
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

            <model.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:background="@color/primary_color"/>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="activity.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

tab_1.xml (pretty much the same as tab_2.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="You Are In Tab 1"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

NavDrawerItem.java

```
public class NavDrawerItem {

    private boolean showNotify;
    private String title;


    public NavDrawerItem() {

    }

    public NavDrawerItem(boolean showNotify, String title) {
        this.showNotify = showNotify;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public boolean isShowNotify() {
        return showNotify;
    }

    public void setShowNotify(boolean showNotify) {
        this.showNotify = showNotify;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

NavigationDrawerAapter.java

```
public class NavigationDrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NavigationDrawerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    List<NavDrawerItem> data = Collections.emptyList();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public NavigationDrawerAdapter(Context context, List<NavDrawerItem> data) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void delete(int position) {
        data.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_row, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        NavDrawerItem current = data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(current.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
    int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created


    // Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
        super(fm);

        this.Titles = mTitles;
        this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

    }

    //This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
        {
            Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
            return tab1;
        }
        else             // As we are having 2 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
        {
            Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
            return tab2;
        }


    }

    // This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return Titles[position];
    }

    // This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NumbOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Comment: For swipeable views I am assuming you are using ViewPager, so do you load the same fragments whatever be the navigation drawer selection?

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal Yeah. I don't know how to different fragments by selecting another nav drawer selection

Comment: Do you know how to detect navigation drawer element selection i.e. which element is selected?

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal Not really. Would you be able to help me on that?

Comment: Yes, I might be able to help. Could you post some code which you are using so that I can provide specific details?

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal Ok. I'll post some code

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal Is that enough code?

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal If you want to know what I followed to make this. http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html for the tabs and http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/ for the navigation drawer

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/). It has your exact requirements. The following functions should be useful for you. Try it out. It handles navigation drawer, and navigation drawer item clicks.

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}
```

and

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


switch (position) {

case 0:

    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment1, Constants.TAG_FRAGMENT).commit();

    break;


case 1:
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment2, Constants.TAG_FRAGMENT);

    ft.commit();
    break;

}

mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
setTitle(title[position]);

// Close drawer
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

}

Comment: Thanks. But that link only has navigation drawer. No swipe able views. I am talking about an app like Poketcasts or Paperboy.